# Google Sheets Query function incorrectly sorts numerical values

Tags: sql, sorting, google-sheets

Hello fellow Stack Overflowers!
First of all - I cannot share the file I'm working on since it contains confidential company data.
I'm building a raport/file that will assist my team in ordering spare parts. In order to do that, I've decided to create a *query builder* which will output what I want based on conditions that are inputted:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D2Ti.png)
From top to bottom:
**Filtruj po dostawcy** - Filter by supplier - Select which supplier You'd like to have outputted (or all of them),
**Sortowanie**- Sorting column - Select a column by which the output will be sorted
**Opcje sortowania** - Sorting options - context-sensitive, gives You more options to sort (e.g. sort by estimated stock based on 6 or 24 month history)
**Kierunek sortowania** - Sorting type - ascending or descending
**Uwzględnij pola "b/d" z 24 mies** - Include "N/A" results - select whether You'd like to see all parts, or only those for which we have data to calculate estimated stock

In order to do that, I'v created a query, with internal conditions, which construcs it based on the above conditions:

```
*query*(*Import*!A2:N;"select A,F,G,I,J,K where A is not null
"&*JEŻELI*(B1="WSZYSTKO";"";"and D matches '"&B1&"'")
&*JEŻELI*(B5="NIE";" and not K matches 'b/d'";"")
&*ifs*(B2="Alfabetycznie";" order by A";B3="Bez zamienników";" order by F";B3="Z zamiennikami";" order by G";B3="6 mscy";" order by I";B3="12 mscy";" order by J";B3="24 msce";" order by K")
&*JEŻELI*(B4="Malejąco";" desc";" asc"))
```

As You can see, it has a input range specified, output columns, prefilter to exclude null results, and then constructs the query.
The problem is that sorting is all wrong. When I sort alphabetically by part number, all dandy, but when I try to sort by numerical values, it behaves like it would be sorting alphabatically by those values:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42CyV.png)

I've tried to simply format them as numbers - no change.
Forcing the input data to be numbers (by using TO_VALUE function) is no go.
Maybe the problem is that some values are strings ("b/d" - which basically means that I have no data to show and this is a placeholder)?

My dream result is... the query outputting correctly sorted data.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe tells that the values are not numbers but text strings that look like numbers. Try **Insert > Sheet**, name the new sheet `Import2`, and put this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    len(Import!A2:A), 
    iferror( 
      value( 1 / Import!A2:N ^ -1 ), 
      Import!A2:N 
    ), 
    iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```

Then format the data in the new sheet the way you want, and replace `Import!A2:N` in your `query()` formula with `Import2!A2:N`.

> I'd much rather have "b/d" than zero, as one notifies us that there is no data to show

Use blanks instead of zeros to show that a piece of data is missing. Alternatively, use custom number formatting to show zeros as `b/d`.

Comment: Looks like I can see what is the problem. Query function will treat all the data as it would a "least denominator" - being a text string. As there are values of "b/d" there, which are undobtedly strings, all numbers are also treated as strings. If I replace all of them with 0 (zeroes), everything works perfectly. Now the problem is that I'd much rather have "b/d" than zero, as one notifies us that there is no data to show, and the other shows that there is data, but we have no stock left... Is it possible?

Comment: The `query()` function will only accept one data type per column, so if your data columns contain a mix of text and numbers, or the occasional date or Boolean, the majority type will rule, and other types will be returned as nulls. You are saying that the data comes through, which means that the "numbers" in that column are text strings that just look like numbers.

Answer (score 0):

And if you leave the sorting part outside of the query? I think you'd be able to overcome the given limitations. Try implementing your conditionals about order but as column numbers of SORT and 1 or 0 for ascending or descending. Sorry I don't try to do it myself but I'm afraid of mixing up because of language limitations, if you give access to a spreadsheet I may be able to help more

[SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en)

> Syntax
>
> SORT(put here your query, sort_column-numbers 1 to 6-, is_ascending-1
> for asc and 0 for desc-, [sort_column2, is_ascending2, ...])

Comment: Sorry, external access to the sheet is impossible. Does sort behave differently than Query?

Comment: Honestly I'm not able of ensuring you that you'll have your desired result. Do this, give it a try: =SORT(YOUR_QUERY,3,1) Change 3 for the number of column you have those numbers (from 1 to 6 that you have as a result of the query)

Comment: There are other options that may let you sort them if you previously import the data in an auxiliary sheet

Comment: I'd rather not migrate the sorting outside of the query as it will greatly complicate the formula. I might try it, just for the fun of it though...

Comment: I've did just that - to no avial. SORT function still gets as input an array with text strings so  the sorting is still broken...